# When I run a command yarn i keep getting unmet peer dependency. How to get rid of those warning

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, dependencies

I cloned my react-native project from Bit-bucket.

`cd /path/to/project/`

`yarn`

And I get the below-mentioned warning

```
warning " > react-native-looped-carousel@0.1.13" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native@^0.54.0".
warning " > react-navigation-stack@1.10.3" has incorrect peer dependency "react-native-screens@^1.0.0 || ^1.0.0-alpha".
warning " > @react-native-community/eslint-config@0.0.5" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react@7.12.4" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-eslint-comments@3.1.2" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=4.19.1".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > babel-eslint@10.0.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>= 4.12.1".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-flowtype@2.50.3" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=2.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-jest@22.4.1" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@>=5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-hooks@1.7.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.0.0 || ^4.0.0 || ^5.0.0 || ^6.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > eslint-plugin-react-native@3.6.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^3.17.0 || ^4 || ^5".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin@1.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/parser@1.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@^5.0.0".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.17.1" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning "@react-native-community/eslint-config > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > @typescript-eslint/experimental-utils@1.13.0" has unmet peer dependency "eslint@*".
```

And also I'm not getting an auto suggestion which I used to get earlier. What am I missing?

Comment: Peer dependencies are not included by the library but expected to be used in the project. You need to add those as dependencies of your own project. So for example, to get rid of the first warning you can add `react-native` version `^0.54.0` to your own dependencies.

Comment: Note that you can also get this warning if you already have that dependency (or dev dependency), but a too recent version (e.g `eslint` 6.x). You have a couple packages there that have a peer dependency for *at most* version 5 so it may not work as expected if you're using version 6 in your project.